# Npm run prod with Laravel Mix and localhost:8080

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, laravel-mix-vue3, laravel-environment

I would like to know how I can use APP_URL from my .env file in the layout. Currently, I have the following.

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(mix('css/styles.css')) }}">
<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

// Styles
mix.sass('resources/scss/styles.scss', 'public/css')
.options({
    postCss: [ tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js') ],
});

// Javascript [Dashboard]
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
.vue();
```

However, when I run `npm run prod` and push on my server, the layout would always load like the following.

```
GET https://localhost:8080/css/styles.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED2023:19 
GET https://localhost:8080/js/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I set in my .env:

```
APP_URL=myurl.com
```

But the website would like to load localhost:8080 again. I use laravel-mix 6.0.27

Comment: change your `APP_URL` to production domain before running `npm run prod`

Comment: thank you for your answer @Joseph ! I have same result when I change the APP_URL and execute after npm run prod.